# Java Swing TitledBorder Customizing Color

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, border

I'm stuck on something silly (it feels that way). I'm trying to create a Java TitledBorder with a specific Color for the border and the Title.

```
Border varBorder;

// this works (creates red border with black text)
varBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED);
varBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(lv_border, "Info");

// this crashes
varBorder.setTitleColor(Color.RED);

varBorder.setBorder(lv_border);
```

What is the correct way to set the color of a TitleBorder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code varBorder is of Border type. You may cast it to TitledBorder or change the type of variable. In Border class there is no such method like setTitleColor.

Comment: Oh I see, I thought these methods applied to Border type variables, thanks a bunch